# receiving dropdown select name with php

Tags: php

A dropdown select name is **birth[month]**, how can i receive the name when form is posted? I'm trying following, which doesnt work (If i use a simple name, for example month, it receives fine).

```
if ($_POST["submit"]) {
$month = $_POST["birth[\"month\"]"];
echo $month;
}
```

Comment: start here: http://www.spsu.edu/cs/faculty/bbrown/papers/php2.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo $_POST['birth']['month'];
```

If posts name is name[index], then it is passed as an aray.

For example:

```
<input name="arr[key1]" value="val1" type="text" />
<input name="arr[key2]" value="val2" type="text" />
<input name="arr[key3]" value="val3" type="text" />
```

when posted, looks like this in php:

```
$_POST['arr'] = array(
"key1" => "val1",
"key2" => "val2",
"key3" => "val3",
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference it like thus:

```
$_POST['birth']['month']
```

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST['birth']['month']` would be the proper way to access the value from `<select name="birth[month]">...</select>`.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect:

`$post['birth']['month']`